# Problem with special character when using c# api

Tags: c#, asp.net, api

i have a problem with using character when i want to get user information by using email
the problem is special character in the email

because the api link not supports character for example

```
this is the Route im using in the api
[Route("api/v1/Users/{Email}")]

and this is the link
api/v1/Users/majed email.com
```

any special character let the GET not even see the request link
how can i solve this problem ?!

Comment: The link you showed is just plain invalid, you cannot have spaces in a URL, they will need to be [URL encoded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding)

Comment: its not space , but the website here cant post the special character , its denaid, its majed@email.com

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In most scenarios it has been found that a 404 is returned if an email address is sent. The issue is usually caused by the "." in the email address.

If you add a trailing slash it should resolve your issue.

```
api/v1/Users/majed@email.com/
```

Comment: It's work. But I need this URL structure because I am supposed to use this URL to open a new instance of Office Word through the browser. Do you have any idea to tackle this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You could use URL encoded format of the string.
The string `majed@email.com` would encoded be `majed%40email.com`.
You can read more at [W3 Shools URL Encoding Reference](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp).

Comment: this solved the problem. api/v1/Users/majed@email.com/